# jQuery loop inside of a string?

Tags: ajax, jquery

Here I am in a jQuery loop and all I am doing is making a string and appending it to a div. Very simple so far right?

Well I am also looping inside of my loop. The problem is my loop inside of my loop is generating the exact same result.

So my first loop I am looping through some TV Channels and my 2nd loop I am looping through some TV Shows. The problem is my TV shows are all the same for every channel. Pretty dumb cable network right?

How can I loop through all the TV Shows and attach them to the correct TV Channel?

```
shows='';
// loop through the tv channels
$(playlist).each(function(i,value){


// loop through the tv shows
$(value.videos).each(function(i,value){
    shows += '<div class="show"><a href="#"><p>'+tv show+'</p></a></div>';
}); end tv show loop

string = '<div class="channel">'+
            '<h1>value.name</h1>'+
            '<div class="shows">'+shows+'</div>'+
        '</div>';


$(string).appendTo('#streams');


}); // end tv chanel loop
```

What I want the html output to look like

```
<div class="channel">
<h1>channel name</h1>
<div class="shows">
    <div class="show"><a href="#"><p>show name</p></a></div>
    <div class="show"><a href="#"><p>show name</p></a></div>
    <div class="show"><a href="#"><p>show name</p></a></div>
</div>
```

```
<!-- repeat again -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple problems

1. the variable `shows` need to be reseted in every `playlist` loop
2. `value.name` is a variable value so it cannot be added as a string
3. `tv show` might has to be changed to `tv.show`

Try

```
// loop through the tv channels
$(playlist).each(function(i, value) {
    var shows = '';

    // loop through the tv shows
    $(value.videos).each(function(i, tv) {
        shows += '<div class="show"><a href="#"><p>' + tv.show
                + '</p></a></div>';
    }); // end tv show loop

    string = '<div class="channel">' + '<h1>' + value.name + '</h1>'
            + '<div class="shows">' + shows + '</div>' + '</div>';

    $(string).appendTo('#streams');

}); // end tv chanel loop
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/8mQpX/1/)

Answer (score 1):

you need to use `shows='';` inside the first loop

```
// loop through the tv channels
$(playlist).each(function(i,value){
shows='';
........
});
```

You need to empty the `shows` string for new channel.But you are not doing it.So it is appending to the previous string continuously